# As an ActiveMQ subscriber how can I get the message publisher username or any other identifier to be used later?

Tags: activemq-classic, mqtt, iot

As an ActiveMQ subscriber I want to know the user name of the message publisher or any identifier on receiving the message. I'm using the MQTT protocol and the flow of message received from ActiveMQ broker will be saved according to provided identifier.

I have another constraints. The authorized publisher will just publish only the data on specified topic and will not provide any extra identifier value with the data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Typically in this kind of situation you'd set [`populateJMSXUserID="true"`](http://activemq.apache.org/jmsxuserid.html) in your `activemq.xml` and then when you receive the message you could just look at the `JMSXUserID` property. However, since MQTT doesn't support message properties this almost certainly won't work for you.

I think you'd probably have to write your own [broker plugin](https://activemq.apache.org/developing-plugins) to modify the *body* of the MQTT message with the necessary identifier.

Comment: lately, we tried to implement a broker plugin but we faced a lot of issues, the "message delivered" override method did not triggered, only add and remove connection work, after a lot of search all solutions did not work.

So we decided to intercept and update the message with "Apache Camel" and route the message again to another topic and it works well.

After that we decided to use Apache Nifi for data ingestion purpose, so we find that there is a processor component called "Consume JMS" it perform the task without any interception or modification.

Thank you for your response.